# two table input parameters in stored procedure

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I am working on C# project which needs a stored procedure which will take two table names as inputs.

First table will copy data to a temp table which has two columns `URL` & `channelID`. This `URL` column is then matched with other input table's URL column & if match is found then it will update channel id from temp table to other tables channel ID.

I have written stored procedure as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateTables]
    @excelTable NVARCHAR(128) ,
    @TableName NVARCHAR(128) 
AS 
    Declare @channel_Id nvarchar(50)
    Declare @url varchar(400)
BEGIN
    Select * 
    Into #Temp 
    From QUOTENAME(@excelTable)
END 

While EXISTS(SELECT * From #Temp ) > 0
Begin
   Select Top 1 
       @channel_Id = channel_Id, @url = url  
   From #Temp

   update QUOTENAME(@TableName) 
   set channelid = @channelid 
   where pagefullurl like '%'+ @url + '%'

   Delete #Temp 
   Where channelid = @channelid
End
```

I don't have much knowledge in `TSQL` and my above code has errors.

> Incorrect syntax near '>'.
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure UpdateTables, Line 20
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@channelid".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure UpdateTables, Line 22
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@channelid".

Please suggest what changes needs to done

Comment: You cannot parameterize table names directly - you'd have to use dynamic SQL. It's also not at all clear to me why you're doing this as separate steps rather than just doing `UPDATE ts SET ... FROM ExcelTable t1 JOIN TableName t2 ON ...`. SQL is a set-based language. Don't break everything down into *procedural* code.

Comment: not using join because i dont have any column to join....dont know whether we can join using like clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have MS SQL server handy to test it, but you declare your variable as `@channel_Id`, and later try to use it as `@channelid` (without the underscore) so you get errors about the undeclared variable.

Comment: @dhruv...thanx for correcting stored procedure. i put 'END' at wrong position. also forgot to remove > 0

Answer (score 0):

I've corrected your SP and this is how it should look

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateTables]
    @excelTable NVARCHAR(128) ,
    @TableName NVARCHAR(128) 
AS 
    Declare @channel_Id nvarchar(50)
    Declare @url varchar(400)
BEGIN
    Select * 
    Into #Temp 
    From QUOTENAME(@excelTable)

While EXISTS(SELECT * From #Temp ) 
Begin
   Select Top 1 
       @channel_Id = channel_Id, @url = url  
   From #Temp

   update QUOTENAME(@TableName) 
   set channelid = @channel_Id 
   where pagefullurl like '%'+ @url + '%'

   Delete #Temp 
   Where channelid = @channel_Id
End
END
```